# Microtype package v 3.0a with documentclass `book` in \maketitle: bug

Tags: document-classes, microtype, scrbook, bugs

I found a bug when I use `microtype` package v 3.0a with documentclass `book` in `\maketitle` macro.

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex
% !TeX encoding = utf8

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{microtype}

\title{My title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

> (d:/Programs/LaTeX/TeXLive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-cmr.cfg
> File: mt-cmr.cfg 2013/05/19 v2.2 microtype config. file: Computer
> Modern Roman  (RS) ) Runaway argument? {\scantokens {\LARGE @title  !
> Paragraph ended before \MT@prot@l was complete. 
> \par  l.10 \maketitle
> I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this control sequence to too much text. How can we recover? My plan is
> to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
>
> ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \MT@prot@group@@ ...er {\the
> \MT@toks \noexpand }}
> }\endgroup  l.10 \maketitle
> I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and you forgot something else, as in` \hbox{$x}'. In such cases the way to
> recover is to insert both the forgotten and the deleted material,
> e.g., by typing `I$}'.
>
> ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \MT@prot@group@@ ...r {\the
> \MT@toks \noexpand }}}
> \endgroup  l.10 \maketitle
> I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and you forgot something else, as in` \hbox{$x}'. In such cases the way to
> recover is to insert both the forgotten and the deleted material,
> e.g., by typing `I$}'.

When I call the `microtype` after `\title`, no error occurs.

Interesting thing, behaves well in this regard `scrbook`, because no such error occurs.

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex
% !TeX encoding = utf8

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{microtype}

\title{My title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```